# How to determine SQL server version number for Compact edition 4 up to full sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce-4

Lot's of people have asked and been responded to about how to determine the version of the sql server using things like @@VERSION, or SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') but none of these work with sql server compact edition 4.

Is there some universally supported method to determine which sql server edition and version is in use through a sql query or ado.net code that works for compact edition all the way to full sql server?

I want to determine which exact edition / version of SQL server is in use so I know what type of paging query to issue from my code.  Sql CE 4 uses a new format for paging queries same as sql server 2011 (denali) and 2005 and 2008 have their own method that is unsupported in CE 4.

I think the answer is that it's impossible but I just want to be sure I didn't overlook something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really work with SQL Server anymore but here is my attempt at this little problem.

For version 4 of compact edition the following should give you the version and build.

```
var ver = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection().ServerVersion;
```

And the following should give you the assembly version

```
var version = typeof(System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection).Assembly.GetName().Version;
```

Comment: Thanks Gareth, it's what I ultimately ended up doing.  Not how I wanted to do it but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this blog post](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/08/sql-server-compact-version-detector.html). It has a [link to download](http://cid-47e59e4beb70472b.office.live.com/self.aspx/SQL%20Compact/SQL%20Compact%20Version%20Detect/SQL%20Compact%20Detector.zip) a utility that detects which version of SQL Compact edition you're running. It also has a [link to the source code](http://cid-47e59e4beb70472b.office.live.com/self.aspx/SQL%20Compact/SQL%20Compact%20Version%20Detect/SdfVersionDetect.zip) for the utility which may be of interest to you.

Comment: Hi Jason, sorry I wasn't specific enough I guess.  I need a way to know via a sql query what version of sql server I'm connected to so that my code can issue the appropriate format of paging query.

Comment: @JohnC, Looking at the SQL Server Compact Edition Function List (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174077%28SQL.100%29.aspx) it doesn't look like there is a function to return which version is running via TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell , in versions of Windows 7 or newer , it comes pre- installed by default. Use the following command lines :

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("SQLCeAssembly.dll").GetName().Version
```

Outputs this:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      0      0
```

Answer (score -2):

run this

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

See details [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185)

Comment: The methods in that link will work for all versions of SQL Server except Compact edition which is one of the versions the OP listed in his question.